# Crear formulario online para completar y enviar respuestas a una base da datos

Tags: base-de-datos, powerbi, microsoft-office

necesito de algunas sugerencias para resolver el siguiente problema:

Trabajo en una planta que opera 4 horas por días, para cada operación diaria los técnicos tienen que completar un formulario de muestras.
Actualmente los formularios se completan manualmente, pero ahora se necesita que sean completados por medio de alguna plataforma online, de preferencia alguna de Microsoft y cada respuesta diaria tiene que ser enviada a una base de datos, puede ser algún Excel. Para luego esos datos ser tratados y visualizados en Power Bi

Uno de los formularios tiene el siguiente formato:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He realizo algunos test en plataformas como Microsoft Froms e Forms Google, dónde es poco practico e poco intuitivo rellenar una tabla con valores numéricos.

Alguien sabe alguna herramienta o idea que para generar ese mismo tipo de formulario dinámico online, y que las respuestas sean enviadas en un témplate de Excel

Desde ya, agradezco su tiempo

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo utilizar Power Apps, puedes utilizar una plantilla prediseñada para crear una app en la que técnicos ingresen las respuestas del formulario y luego puedes añadir una conexión a Excel para depositar los datos allí.

[Plantilla de Power App/ Employee Engagement Survey](https://apps.powerapps.com/play/b79a7234-c22f-4f77-8fc5-6dcedb7f4ab1?source=portal&screenColor=rgba(1%2C%20131%2C%20134%2C%201))

Te tocará ser autodidacta pero se puede lograr con un poco de investigación.